# how to build 64 bit managed c++ dll in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, managed-c++

I've got a managed c++ dll, and it builds fine in x86 format. However, when I change the format to x64 in configuration manager, it won't recognize .Net namespaces, like System etc.

What else should I change to be able to build the 64-bit version of the app?

I'll need to be able to build the app for x64 and for x86.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you changed your project to target x64, the settings that tell the compiler to target the .NET Framework obviously didn't get transferred over.

Check your project's properties to ensure that all of the x64 settings match with the x86 settings.

More specifically, you're looking for the "Common Language Runtime Support" property. On recent versions of Visual Studio, this should probably be set to `Common Language Runtime Support, Old Syntax (/clr:oldSyntax)` for Managed C++.

[image]

Comment: yes, the clr was disabled, set it to Common Language Runtime Support (/clr). Now I'm getting following linker error:"error LNK1561: entry point must be defined". Any idea on what else is missing?

Comment: @Arsen: [Check MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky737ya4.aspx). You say that you're building a DLL, but your project's "Configuration Type" property (see above screenshot) is probably set to build an executable. Change it to build a DLL. And as I suggested, check the other properties to ensure that they match your working x86 configuration.

Comment: ok. got it. The configuration type must had been set to dynamic library, and that has fixed it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You would create an 'x64' configuration there is a second drop down box for 'copy settings from'. That also has to be properly set to copy setting from your other configurations.

But since you have already done that, perhaps all your assembly referenences didn't copied over to your 'x64' configuration. Have you checked in your x64 project settings to see if they are there? Open up your project settings and select:
**Common Properties -> Framework and References**
Then make sure you have a reference to System (At least)

Comment: the references are there, but they are pointing to the files inside C:\Program Files (x86)\ folder

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll

Comment: Yeah, that is perfectly fine.